# intellij idea doesn't update properties file

Tags: intellij-idea, properties-file

my project has a `messages_tr.properties` file outside of any sub-module. It is configured by this xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="...ExposedResourceBundleMessageSource"> // derived from ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>file://${PROP_PATH}/messages</value>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="40"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
</bean>
```

When I run project in debug mode, it works just fine. But, any change to the `messages_tr.properties` doesn't reflect. Neither editing any key-value pair, nor adding a new one.

I thought it maybe a Intellij Cache problem and tried several combinations of:

- `Invalidate Caches / Restart`
- `Close Project, delete all .iml + .idea + target`
- `restart computer`
- `Rebuild + mvn clean install -DskipTests -P Profile`
- `File -> Synchronize`
- `VCS -> Refresh File Status`
- try on IE and Chrome Incognito, Chrome ctrl-f5
- add `?*.properties` to `Settings -> Compiler -> Resource Patterns`

I don't want to create a new property file just for this problem, and also it may not work too. I just run out of ideas.

**What may prevent Intellij IDEA to update a property file? How can I resolve this?**

**EDIT:** I have a key-value pair in this messages_tr.properties file like `key = abcd` and I edit it with editor to `key = abcd222`. Or I add a new pair `key2 = abcd222`. In the 1st case, message still comes as `abcd` and in the 2nd case, I get an error saying `there is no key like key2`. I mean editing content doesn't work.

PROP_PATH is a folder outside of any project module, here absolute path method is used. PROP_PATH is configured via `server.xml` in `websphere` configuration wlp folder. This configuration works, but editing doesn't reflect.

Comment: What do you mean by "update"? From which directory is your application trying to read the .properties file? In other words, what is PROP_PATH in your snippet?

Comment: @yole Thanks for reply. Please see my edit at below of question. BTW, this properties file is outside of the project folder I compile to make .war file.

Comment: @yole You were right, the path was set externally in VM options. I realized that much later, and forgot even asking this question. I will accept if you give this as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to solve it, @kalahari? I was about to submit a bug report to Jetbrains  for this...

Comment: @Pere, sorry I have no memory about this issue.